# Remove duplicate data from dynamic select option of HTMl form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, html-select

In my website's database, there are a lot of posts inserted with the date. I am making a post shorting system where a user selects a year from the dynamic dropdown and after pressing the submit button only that year's post will be visible on the website. Everything is going good but on the dynamic dropdown, a year is showing multiple time.

For example, There are 3 posts in my database which date is 2/2/2019 , 21/2/2019 , 22/3/2019. In my dynamic dropdown there I find 2019 3 times, but I need to show 2019 only one time.

I have tried some jQuery and JavaScript code but it did not work.

My code :

```
<?php        
    $query = "SELECT year(date) FROM `press_release` WHERE del_status=0";
    $year = $conn->query($query);
?>

<form class="form-inline title" action="press_new.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" style="color:#EB2227">Search by year</label>
        <select name="year">
            <option value="0">Please Select</option>

            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($year)){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo($row['year(date)'])?>">
                    <?php echo($row['year(date)']) ?>
                </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#EB2227">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `DISTINCT` ?

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT year(date) FROM `press_release` WHERE del_status=0";
```

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

Select unique/distinct years instead of just year in your sql query.

```
<?php 

        $query = "SELECT distinct year(date) FROM `press_release` WHERE del_status=0";
        $year = $conn->query($query);
        ?>

        <form class="form-inline" class="title" action="press_new.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" style="color:#EB2227">Search by year</label>
                <select name="year">
                    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
                    <?php
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($year))
                        {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo($row['year(date)'])?>">
                        <?php echo($row['year(date)']) ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php
                        }               
                    ?>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:#EB2227">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Problem Solved. Thank You very much